# emacs kbd macro - record key incorrectly

Tags: emacs

According to this [post](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/06/21/eval-and-replace/), I have defined eval-and-replace in my .emacs file.

However when I tried to eval and replace the following list of sexp using a macro, it will mess up on my mac. Whereas on my Linux machine or just do eval-and-replace with a single sexp, it will work.

```
(+ 1 2)
(+ 1 2)
(+ 1 2)
(+ 1 2)
(+ 1 2)
```

So starting from the beginning of each sexp, the macro I defined is the following: `C-e C-c e <down> C-a`.

But when I ran the macro stepper the actual macro is `C-e C-e C-c C-c ee <down> C-a`. I am wondering how come it will record some commands twice.

And I also got an error from the macro stepper `Error in post-command-hook (kmacro-step-edit-post-command): (void variable kmacro-step-edit-active`

According to the wiki `post-command-hook` is related to the previous command. But I have no clues about how to resolve this.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you running on each machine?

Comment: Use `C-h l` after recording the macro to confirm which keystrokes Emacs saw when you were recording? This could simply be a hardware issue with the keyboard on the Mac. `C-x C-k e RET` will also invoke the macro editor for the most recent keyboard macro.

Comment: @phils Hi, when I type `C-h l`, the recorded keystrokes are `C-h C-h l l`. But if this is a hardware problem, then when I don't use macro, why everything is fine? And when I just type `l` for instance, only one `l` will occur?

Comment: @phils And the version of emacs on both machines are 24.

Comment: So you can type normally with no duplications, but `C-h l` shows everything (or many things) that you typed as doubled? That sounds seriously strange. Outside of my understanding, at any rate. Can you confirm that this happens with `emacs -Q` as well?

Comment: @phils Thanks for your help. It seems things will run properly with out my .emacs file.

Comment: Great. You should probably *recursively bisect* your config until you find out what was causing that, and then post an answer here to indicate the cause of the problem.

Comment: @phils Hi, I have found the problem in my .emacs file. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After commenting out some parts in my .emacs file, I have found that there is a bug in the flash-paren.el file, which flashes the paren while defining a kbd macro but not executing a macro.

By adding `(not (defining-kbd-macro))` in `flash-paren-check` function solves the problem.

So it is not a hardware problem.

Comment: Nice one. Be sure to submit a bug report to the author.

Comment: @phils Thank you very much! I have sent a pull request.